# Text not visible in text field

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in my navigation bar which, when pressed, calls a function (showAddItemtextField) that shows a text field as a titleView in the navigation bar.

```
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showAddItemTextField))
```

That much is ok so far, and I can type text into the text field (I know because when I tap on the text field the placeholder text disappears, and when I type I get autocomplete suggestions), but the text I type is otherwise invisible.

Here's my code so far:

```
// Show text field upon add button press
lazy var addItemTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Add a new item..."

    return textField
}()

func showAddItemTextField() {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = addItemTextField

}
```

I'm not sure if the issue is because the new text field, as a navigationItem.titleView, goes on top of what is usually there (navigationItem.title). Do I have to hide navigationItem.title when the text field is present? Or is a different problem?

I should also add that the onscreen keyboard does not appear when I tap on the text field.

Comment: Your code for `showAddItemTextField` makes no sense. You cannot add the same text field both as a subview to `self.view` and as a title view to your `navigationItem`.

Comment: @matt I'll remove addSubview, I realize now it's unnecessary, although I don't think that's what's causing my problem. Do you know of a solution to get the text to appear in my text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your text field has no size. You failed to give it a size when you created it, when you said:

```
let textField = UITextField()
```

Then you compounded the problem by the unnecessary `textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` line.

This works fine for me:

```
    let tf = UITextField(frame:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:CGSize(width:100, height:28)))
    tf.borderStyle = .bezel
    self.navigationItem.titleView = tf
```

I'm not saying that that's the size / look you want, but it makes a visible text field you can type into.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints was for programmatic constraints if I went that route but I removed it and gave the text field a size, and now everything looks good, except for the keyboard not showing up but I bet that's a simple fix which I can find. Thanks again.

Comment: On my machine the keyboard shows up when I click in the text field, which is right. If you want to the text field to summon the keyboard programmatically, make it the first responder.

Comment: I tried textField.becomeFirstReponder() inside addItemtextField (I'm assuming that's the proper place? Sorry I'm quite new) and the keyboard doesn't show up.

Comment: Probably too soon. — Also be sure to fiddle with the simulator's onscreen keyboard settings, as it can definitely mislead you in this regard.

Comment: not working in my case i added size and try to load text on click listener but same result